# Select preferred DNS in NetworkManager when more connections are active

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, systemd-resolved

Good morning.

I have this situation, in which I have the primary interface `eth0` set with its DNS, and I set a second interface (connection in NetworkManager) up, `tun0`, which is a VPN, but NetworkManager is NOT aware of it. For NetworkManager is just another connection. Indeed I can NOT use options as for example `connection.secondaries` etc... I mean, I do NOT use any NetworkManager plugin for VPN, it is just a second connection that is "up".

AFAIK, NetworkManager will use `systemd-resolved` to set DNS, since the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is a symlink to `/run/systemd/...` and the default behaviour of NetworkManager should be to set the DNS through resolved. Indeed no configuration in NetworkManager is set to say otherwise.

Indeed I can see the changes in the eth0 DNS reflected in `/run/systemd/...`. Furthermore, if I remove the DNS from eth0, NetworkManager will take the ones in `tun0`, so I can affirm that I set the DNS in `tun0` correctly.

So, now I want to use the DNS in `tun0`, but I do NOT want to modify the eth0 connection. Since `eth0` is the primary connection (it has the `autoconnect=yes` and more priority), I see that the DNS always used are the ones in `eth0`.

I try to set the priority in `tun0` in many ways, for example using the option `ipv4.dns-priority`, but I had no luck.

So, my first question is:

- How can I tell NetworkManager to use the DNS from `tun0`, without modifying the fist connection eth0 (both connections are "up")?

Since I was not able to do that, I was looking for an alternative: since `resolved` should be able to use multiple DNS at the same time, each DNS bound to an interface, I though that maybe it was possible to activate both DNS in `eth0` and `tun0`, and then blocking one of them using Firewall rules. Again, no luck, if the DNS from `eth0` are blocked, I will have no DNS at all, so the ones set in `tun0` are not used at all in this situation.

So, my second question is:

- How can I tell NetworkManager to set BOTH DNS (since I use resolved, it should be possible because resolved allows the use of multiple DNS bound to different interfaces) so they will be all used (and I will manage them with firewall)?

**EDIT**

As suggested in comments, I add that I am testing with Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Thanks, added it